# How do I recreate a mysql data source connection, if the connection fails, in java?

Tags: java, mysql, eclipse

I have created a mysqlDatasource connection using the following code:

```
MysqlDataSource d = new MysqlDataSource();
d.setUser("user");
d.setPassword("pass");
d.setServerName("hostname.com");
d.setDatabaseName("db");
Connection c = d.getConnection();
```

If Im running my application and the connections are disconnected because mysql restarted or for some other reason, the remaining operations will fail even if the mysql server instance is running.

In that case I want to recreate a connection? Is this possible?  How do I go about doing this?

Answer (score 0):

In most cases when you're creating multiple connections and juggling them, it's better to use a connection pool, where the `Connection` objects are just that, objects, and are multiplexed to actual socket connections handled by an underlying implementation. This means that connections are created automatically when you need them and you don't need to worry about reclaiming resources and creating an appropriate number of connections.

Two prominent examples are [BoneCP](http://jolbox.com/) and [C3P0](http://sourceforge.net/projects/c3p0/).

Answer (score 0):

The other option, in addition to Mr Mao's, is to define the [url explicitly](http://www.docjar.com/docs/api/com/mysql/jdbc/jdbc2/optional/MysqlDataSource.html#setURL%28String%29) using setURL to allow for automatic reconnection, using the [autoReconnect parameter](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/connector-j-reference-configuration-properties.html), do note, though, that this approach is not recommended. The answer is provided here only for completeness.

Answer (score 0):

Just take an help of [DBCP CONNECTION](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-dbcp//) and create your Connection pool like below code. You can see there is `validation query` which pings database at regular interval and refreshes the pool. There are other property like `validateConnection` you can set this property to `true`.

```
BasicDataSource dataSource = new BasicDataSource();

dataSource.setDriverClassName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
dataSource.setUsername("username");
dataSource.setPassword("password");
dataSource.setUrl("jdbc:mysql://<host>:<port>/<database>");
dataSource.setMaxActive(50);
dataSource.setMaxIdle(5);
dataSource.setInitialSize(5);
dataSource.setValidationQuery("SELECT 1");
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

```
String driver = "com.microsoft.jdbc.sqlserver.SQLServerDriver";
Class.forName(driver);
String url = "jdbc:microsoft:sqlserver://host:1433/database";
Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection(url, "username", "password");
```